# MathJax expands page vertical height after rendering fonts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When MathJax renders the vertical height expands, I would like the container DOM's bottom margin updated after the render (there's supposed to be a 2em margin at the bottom.

I tried adding a footer, it did move the container up a bit from being at bottom=0, but it's still not what I would like. This is a fiddle with the Sticky Footer code from css-tricks.com.

http://jsfiddle.net/4thhsa8c/1/

I also tried appending the footer by using the MathJax listener, neither the MathJax listener nor $(window).load managed to 'bump' the container. Actually appending made the footer float up the page. (and it not like I really what the footer!)

```
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("MathZoom Ready", function() {
        var $newdiv = $("<div class='footer'/>");
        $("body").append( $newdiv );
    });
});
```

SO! How to update or preserve the bottom margin spacing of the container DOM after MathJax renders?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your jsFiddle includes

```
.footer, .bodytext:after {
    height: 45;
}
```

that I think should be

```
.footer, .bodytext:after {
    height: 45px;
}
```

(you are missing the units).  I'm not sure I entirely understand what you are trying to do, but this does seem to leave room at the bottom of the page when I add the units.